# How to reverse the order of wrap layout on angular nativescript

Tags: html, angular, nativescript

I builds a mobile application which shows a vertical column of items when in each line there are 2 items.
for this i use `WrapLayout` to break line after every two items. The problem is that when i have only single item left i want it to be on the right side of the column, but the default is the left. How can i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i just used flexboxLayout with property `flexWrap` set to `Wrap`. Same result and i have controll over the direction